# docker-compose expired SSL not able to update in Spring Boot app

Tags: spring-boot, docker, ssl, docker-compose, certbot

I’ve got an expired SSL certificate in my docker-compose server.

I’m using this config below in my docker-compose.yml

```
certbot:
  image: certbot/certbot:latest
  volumes:
    - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
    - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
  entrypoint: "/bin/sh -c 'trap exit TERM; while :; do certbot renew; sleep 12h & wait $${!}; done;'"
  command: "/bin/sh -c 'while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g \"daemon off;\"'"
```

And this is the nginx config in my Spring Boot app

```
events {
    worker_connections  4096;
}

http {

    server {

        listen              80;
        server_name         app.MYAPP.com;
#       listen              443 ssl;
#       server_name         ${FQDN};
#       ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/${FQDN}/fullchain.pem;
#       ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/${FQDN}/privkey.pem;

        location / {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }

        location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
            root /var/www/certbot;
        }

    }

    server {
        listen              443 ssl;
        server_name         app.MYAPP.com;

        ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.MYAPP.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.MYAPP.com/privkey.pem;
        include             /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
        ssl_dhparam         /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        location / {
                root /www;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        location ~^/api/(?<segment>.*)$ {
                # kill cache
                add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
                add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
                if_modified_since off;
                expires off;
                etag off;

                proxy_pass http://app.MYAPP.com:8080/$segment$is_args$args;
        }
    }
}
```

My frontend makes requests to `app.MYAPP.com:8080` and its throwing `(failed)net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID`

I’m not able to force the SSL regeneration/revalidation from Let’s Encrypt end. I already tried restarting my hostinger server, restarting docker, and, removing all the volumes and docker containers. I also trying doing a force renew of the certificates but the server is still serving the old ones.

[image: expired certificates]